# How to transform a value within an attribute with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Have an XML code as follows (partially):

```
    <ItemMaster>
            <Classification>
                <Codes>
                    <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">Cost</Code>
                    <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">4ET</Code>
                    <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">*</Code>
                </Codes>
            </Classification>   
    </ItemMaster>
```

I want to change the Item Types from "Cost" to "Purchased". So it will look like this :

```
<ItemMaster>
            <Classification>
                <Codes>
                    <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">Purchased</Code>
                    <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">4ET</Code>
                    <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">*</Code>
                </Codes>
            </Classification>   
    </ItemMaster>
```

I want to use the "choose" function, because I need to change the value based on a condition, such as IF the Item Groups is 4ET, then change the Item Types to change to Purchased

usually I can match the element. But now, since the data is inside an attribute, I don't know how to match and change it

UPDATE:
I tried these codes

```
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template
        match="//my:ItemMaster/my:Classification/my:Codes/my:Code[1]">
    <xsl:variable name="ItemGroup" 
        select="//my:ItemMaster/my:Classification/my:Codes/my:Code[@listID='Item Groups']"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="($ItemGroup='4ET')">
                <xsl:element name="Code[1]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Purchased'" />
                </xsl:element>              
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="Code[1]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Cost'" />
                </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And then I got this result :

```
<Classification>
                <Codes>
                    Stock
                    <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">4ET</Code>
                    <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">*</Code>
                </Codes>
            </Classification>
```

So, it is still not like what I needed.

Please help me :(
Thank you for the kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is change 'Cost' to 'Purchased', you could do an identity transform, which means applying a recursive template that simply copies the node, on all nodes, and have a separate template for all text nodes of which the value is 'Cost'.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[. = 'Cost']">
        <xsl:text>Purchase</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Updated code based on response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Code[@listID='Item Types']">
        <xsl:variable name="itemGroup" select="../Code[@listID='Item Groups']"/>
        <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="{@sequence}">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$itemGroup = '4ET'">
                    <xsl:text>Purchased</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$itemGroup = 'something else'">
                    <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            </Code>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually I need to use the Choose like the example on my question. But I will try this out first. Thanks !

Comment: Hi wasmachien, I have tried it, it is not working, because I need to use "choose" function. 

The case is to change the value if a condition was met.
Could you incorporate the answer by using "Choose"?

Comment: @ArnoldyMoniaga something like this?

Comment: @washmachien I have tried, but it is still not right. The result is only a word "Purchased" in one line. It is the same result like I stated above. I need the transformation exactly like <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">Purchased</Code> . Right now, it is only one text : "Purchased"

Comment: @ArnoldyMoniaga When you run the second code snippet on your supplied input XML, the result is ``<Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">Purchased</Code>``. Are you running the correct code?

Comment: @washmachien. Actually, it worked ! but now, there is a namespace there. How can I remove the namespace?

Comment: Hi @washmachien , what is the function of "Code" syntax on the XSLT? thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out please;

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ItemMaster>
        <Classification>
            <Codes>
                <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Purchase'"/>
                </Code>
                <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Code[2]"/>
                </Code>
                <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Code[3]"/>
                </Code>
            </Codes>
        </Classification>
    </ItemMaster>
</xsl:template>
```

When you apply, it will change the value of  your node

Comment: Hi Sojimanatsu,
I have tried it, but it resulted like this :
<Classification>
     <Codes>
      Stock
      <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">4ET</Code>
      <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">*</Code>
     </Codes>
    </Classification>

Comment: I just wanted to give you an idea of Xpath selection, this could be done by many ways, the ugly solution would be in edited code, check it out.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much. The Xpath works. I got another way to select the data. But when it tries to write the result, something is still not right.

Comment: If it is working, please accept the answer, if not tell me the problem and lets fix it

Comment: Hi Sojimanatsu, could you incorporate your solution according to my case ? in my case, I need to change the Item type from "Cost" to "Purchase" IF the item group is "4ET". I hope you are okay with this. Thank you :)

Comment: in other words, it is not working because it is not according to the case.